# how to hide the blinking cursor in a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

hello I'm trying a text box expand and collapse option, the text box expand while clicking on it, and collapse while clicking again on it, there is a placeholder in it, while I'm trying to click again in the text box the blinking cursor appears on the placeholder. please help me to hide the blinking cursor in the text field.

The code for this is:

```
<@spring.formTextarea "messageWallMessage.messageText", "rows=1 cols=1 style='font-size:11px;color:#666666;width:650px; min-height:28px; padding:0 0 0px 1px;margin: 6px 0 -6px 10px;' onkeyup='return showLinkedIcon();' onFocus='if(this.value == 'What\'s on your mind?') { this.value='';showLinkedIconPublish();return false;}' onBlur='return publishMsg();' onClick='return showLinkedIconPublish();'spellcheck='false'"/>
```

Comment: I would have thought the only way to get rid of the blinking cursor is to move focus to another element - presumably this is only a 'problem' when the user is clicking to collapse the text box, rather than expand it. Perhaps in this case, move focus to the next element in the tab order?

Comment: @w3d You can also move the focus to a hidden form field.

Comment: @ reporter - actually there is another div which i'm trying to show and hide in the process of expand and collapse, and after collapse already expanded div it shows as a current text field as while before expanding.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to have the textarea immediately call `blur()` when it gains focus while you want the cursor to be suppressed.  You will of course need to add logic to prevent this behavior once you want the textarea to become selectable.

Here's a basic example:  http://jsfiddle.net/3V8F6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it does not appear that you can alter the look of the text cursor without changing the look of the text along with it. The two are one in the same and part of the way the OS handles text in general (as far as I can tell).

You could make your text white to hide the cursor until someone starts typing, but I'm sure you were hoping for a better solution than that.

Comment: At least on Windows... Changing the text colour does not influence the colour of the cursor. The colour of the cursor appears to be an inverse of the `background-color` - so it is always visible when the control has focus. (On a regular form control that is.)